# Questions about an example??

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFX5Y.png)

https://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/math/issues/mat-15-39-6/mat-39-6-9-1412-44.pdf

I am trying to understand an example 5.7 in p.896. I understand how do we get $e_1$ and $e_2$, but I don't know how to get $e_3$ and $e_4$

Can anyone tell me?

Thank you.

Comment: Please make your title more informative and write an actual question. We should not have to click on links to see what your issue is.

Comment: At a quick glance at the linked image, the paper is _giving_ an ordered quadruple that is easily checked to be orthonormal; there's no derivation required (e.g., there's no claim the last two frame elements are uniquely determined by some criterion).